# How to update variable within obfuscated code

Tags: javascript, oop, variables, global

I have a situation where I must obfuscate some javascript code.

However, I need to update a variable from within the obfuscated code. I don't know of any obfuscator tools that allow for keeping a specific variable name unaltered within the obfuscated code.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

```
var myVariable = false;
```

code to be obfuscated

```
if( x ) {
    $.when(
        // complex logic here
    ).then(function() {
        myVariable = true; 
    }
} else {
    // more logic
}
```

Comment: I haven't seen any obfuscator tool yet that *doesn't* have such an option to keep most globals unaltered.

Comment: Are you saying you need to use the original variable name to change the value? Why can't you just have the logic to change it be obfuscated with the rest of the code?

Comment: Because I need to be able to use the variable again outside of the obfuscated code and once it's obfuscated it's nearly impossible to determine what the new variable name is.

Comment: Which obfuscation tool *did* you use, and with what settings?

Comment: Btw you could always chicken out and just `window["myVariable"] = true`

Comment: Is your goal to make code difficult to read, or just to minify it? UglifyJS minifies the code and enables skipping some names when mangling via the `reserved` config option.

Comment: @Bergi any object would work. Adding it to global (`window`) scope is a bad idea.

Comment: @MarkoGrešak Except the variable holding the reference to the object would be obfuscated as well. OP already has the global variable anyway - they just don't know how to refer to it.

Answer (score 1):

If `myVariable` is a member of a Class, you can use `xClass.prototype["myVariable"] = false;` to declare it rather than writing the variable directly in the class. Then in the class, if you want the object itself, just call `this["myVariable"] = true;`.

If it is under the Window scope, so as somebody else said call `window["myVariable"] = true;` to declare and use it.

If it is in a closure, try to declare to object x and then use x["myVariable"] to declare and use.

Any obfuscater won't minify a string. It should be an obfuscater-independent trick.